# Mongoose version 5.10.6 : MongoDB connection issue with SSL enabled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to mongodb with requireSSL flag enabled from mongod while running mongo instance.

Using Mongoose V5.10.6 driver for connecting to above setup with below options.

```
var ca = fs.readFileSync(<path to certificate.pem file>);
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var options = {
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: ca,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    mongos: true,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: 1000,
    reconnectInterval: 30000,
    dbName: "test"
}

mongoose.connect("mongodb://<username>:<password>@<mongodb_server_name>:<mongodb_port>/adminDb?authSource=admin&ssl=true");
```

But from MongoDB server side where connection accepts only ssl above code is throwing error

```
Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [<server_name>:<server_ip>] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to <server_name>:<server_ip> closed]
at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
at createConnection (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14)
at connect (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11)
at callback (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:97:5)
at runCommand (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:124:7)
at _callback (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
at Connection.errorHandler (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:365:5)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:370:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at TCP._handle.close (net.js:606:12) name: 'MongoNetworkError' }
```

Tried to change options parameter to include server as like below, but still it throwed same error.

```
var options = {
    server: {
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA: ca,
    }
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    mongos: true,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: 1000,
    reconnectInterval: 30000,
    dbName: "test"
}
```

Could you please help me to connect to MongoDB using mongoose via requireSSL enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does driver documentation say is the correct usage in this case?

Comment: driver documentation doesn't have how to connect to ssl system.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Mongoose is not a driver, however that page does reference driver documentation (outdated, for some reason).